# CSS nth-child for menu list with dropdown

Tags: css, html-lists, css-selectors

I have a simple menu with two buttons and each button is a dropdown; each display two sub-buttons. I want for each sub item to be a different background color, as you can see from my CSS below.

```
#nav:first-child > li li:first-child {background: yellow;}
#nav:first-child > li li:nth-child(2) {background: red;}
#nav:nth-child(2) > li li:first-child {background: green;}
#nav:nth-child(2) > li li:nth-child(2) {background: blue;}
```

So far my CSS only works for the first sub-buttons; sub-button one is yellow, and sub-button two is red. Unfortunately sub-button three is yellow instead of green, and sub-button four is red instead of blue. How can I change my last two lines of code to achieve the desired results?

**keep in mind, the dropdown is a nested LIST. HTML example below:

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>link 1
          <ul>
             <li>SUB link 1</li>
             <li>SUB link 2</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>link 2
         <ul>
             <li>SUB link 3</li>
             <li>SUB link 4</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `first-child` and `nth-child` being used incorrectly. It selects the given element only if it is the first-child of its parent. Same with `nth-child`, using the given index. So `#nav:fist-child` selects the `#nav` because it is the first element of the body, but `#nav:nth-child(2)` does not select anything because the `#nav` is not the second child of the body. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: nothing is working in this jsfiddle that I just copied your code from... http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/4TfGh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### IE7-8 Support

You were using `:nth-child` to begin with, which is not supported in those browsers, so I can see why those who answered did not care about support, as it would have appeared that you did not care about such support. However, selectors can be made to work for those. Using the adjacent sibling combinator `+` with the `:first-child` in key points creates the same effect as `:nth-child(2)`

[**See Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDp3j/2/)

```
ul li:first-child > ul li:first-child {background: yellow;}
ul li:first-child > ul li + li {background: red;}
ul li:first-child + li > ul li:first-child {background: green;}
ul li:first-child + li > ul li + li {background: blue;}
```

### IE6

**You cannot get IE6 support** without either javascript or directly putting classes on each of the `li` elements, as IE6 does not support `:first-child` or `+`. Personally, for color variations, you should just let IE6 go. If you insist, and do not want to use javascript to get selector function through that, then you are resolved to change the html:

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>link 1
          <ul>
             <li class="one">SUB link 1</li>
             <li class="two">SUB link 2</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>link 2
         <ul>
             <li class="three">SUB link 3</li>
             <li class="four">SUB link 4</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

With this

```
.one {background: yellow;}
.two {background: red;}
.three {background: green;}
.four {background: blue;}
```

Of course, that would work on *any* browser supporting css. But that is also *not* what I suspect you want to do. So again, leave IE6 to itself and forget about accommodating the color change on that or use javascript (perhaps through [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), [Jquery](http://jquery.com/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), etc.) to do it.

Comment: yea i have included Selectivizr in my Shim.

Answer (score 3):

The `first-child` and `nth-child` should be applied to the `li` tags that are the SUB links.

```
ul li:first-child > ul li:first-child {background: yellow;}
ul li:first-child > ul li:nth-child(2) {background: red;}
ul li:nth-child(2) > ul li:first-child {background: green;}
ul li:nth-child(2) > ul li:nth-child(2) {background: blue;}
```

This will produce the desired results:

http://jsfiddle.net/JDp3j/

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for your expertise.

Comment: I noticed unfortunately in IE6-8 only the first, first child is displaying; the rest are not. I am running .htc but, do I need a certain polyfill to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. Here it is.. Good stuff..  http://selectivizr.com/